# Change instanceof to polymorphism

Tags: java, swing, polymorphism, instanceof, visitor-pattern

How to remove the operator "instanceof" and replace it with polymorphism? Both NamedPlace and DescribedPlace are subclasses to the main class Place.

```
class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev) {           
        p = (Place) mev.getSource();

        if (mev.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
            if (p instanceof NamedPlace) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition(), "Platsinfo: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (p instanceof DescribedPlace) {
                JOptionPane describedPane = new JOptionPane();
                describedPane.setMessage("Name: " + p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition() + "\n" + "Description: " + ((DescribedPlace) p).getDescription());
                describedPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                JDialog dialog = describedPane.createDialog(p, "Platsinfo:");
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/7943564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `Place` the abstract method and add the implementation to the subclasses.

```
abstract class Place {
    // ..
    public abstract void action();
}

class NamedPlace extends Place {
    public void action() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition(), "Platsinfo: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

class DescribedPlace extends Place {
    public void action() {
            JOptionPane describedPane = new JOptionPane();
            describedPane.setMessage("Name: " + p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition() + "\n" + "Description: " + ((DescribedPlace) p).getDescription());
            describedPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JDialog dialog = describedPane.createDialog(p, "Platsinfo:");
            dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and then use this in the listener.

```
class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev) {           
        p = (Place) mev.getSource();

        if (mev.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
            p.action();
        }
    }
}
```

But, depending on what `Place` is exactly, that might not be a good idea (eg if it's not a GUI class).

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to first add an abstract method like `doTheThing()` to your base class.

So that you then simple call `p.doTheThing()` in that listener.

And of course, NamedPlace implements that method to do:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition(), "Platsinfo: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

and the other class implements it to do

```
JOptionPane describedPane = new JOptionPane();
...
```

That technically does what you ask for, but it is also not a very elegant solution. As those two methods are doing really different things.

A *more* reasonable solution could be that you have an abstract method that returns a (formatted) string for example, that then gets added to a (uniform) message window, or something alike.

The point of polymorphism is to allow doing "similar" things using a common interface. It doesn't help with doing completely different things under the same hood.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Place` classes shouldn't be aware of the specific response implementation to a click, then you can use [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and separate your `Place` hierarchy from it's response implementations.

Then you can provide different implementationsfor different situations, and your `Place` classes will not grow and tightly couple with more and more situation specific code.

To achieve that, update your parent class (I prefer to use interface) `Place` with additional method:

```
public interface Place {
    void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

And implement it:

```
public final class NamedPlace {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitNamedPlace(this);
    }
}

public final class DescribedPlace {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitDescribedPlace(this);
    }
}
```

Now the visitor interface will look like this:

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visitNamedPlace(NamedPlace place);
    void visitDescribedPlace(DescribedPlace place);

}
```

The visitor pattern is now ready. And let's use it in your example:

```
class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev) {           
        ((Place) mev.getSource()).accept(new Visitor() {
            @Override
            public void visitNamedPlace(NamedPlace p) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition(), "Platsinfo: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            @Override
            public void visitDescribedPlace(DescribedPlace p) {
                JOptionPane describedPane = new JOptionPane();
                describedPane.setMessage("Name: " + p.getName() + " " + p.getPosition() + "\n" + "Description: " + ((DescribedPlace) p).getDescription());
                describedPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                JDialog dialog = describedPane.createDialog(p, "Platsinfo:");
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Your choice is actually:

- Either to have fixed implementation of response in your classes, and you can extend your hierarchy by adding more of them (earlier responses)
- Or to have fixed hierarchy of classes, and provide dynamically implementations (visitor pattern).

It depends on your use cases.